# Ação de botão depois de clicado - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal

Tenho um botão que quando clicado ele fecha o modal, na verdade ele faz uma ação com CSS fazendo a `div` desaparecer, ficando apenas o botão para ser clicado novamente e abrir o modal. Porém não estou conseguindo criar uma nova ação no mesmo botão, mas agora para abri-lo.

Vejam o código abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bt-fechar").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".box-preco").css("right", "-245px");
    });
});
```

Depois do primeiro clique que fecha o modal, o segundo clique deveria fazer a seguinte ação:

```
$(".box-preco").css("right", "0");
```

Fazendo com que o modal venha para a posição inicial aparecendo na tela. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, pelo que eu entendi, queres criar um efeito de "slider" para mostrar/ocultar uma `div` quando um botão é clicado. Então podes fazê-lo da seguinte maneira:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Se tiveres outro botão ou outro "Trigger" para ser usado, modifica a linha abaixo para por exemplo: $('.bt-fechar, .outraClassFecha').click(function(){
    $('.bt-slide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.box-preco');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-245px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

```css
.box-preco {
    width:150px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-245px;
    background-color:cadetblue;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="bt-slide">Deslizar Painel</a>
<div class="box-preco">Caixa escondida!</div>
```

> Eu mudei o nome da class do botão que antigamente era - `.bt-fechar` para - `.bt-slide` porque faz mais sentido, mas podes mudar isso depois para a tua preferência.

Comment: Perfeito Chun, muito obrigado pela ajuda!